# Design pattern for waiting on asynchronous event handlers

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, asynchronous, promise

There are places in my application where an object should emit an event and should delay execution untill all event handlers have completed work.  The **event handlers might be performing an asynchronous operation** (e.g. writing to database).

```
Application.on("login", function(evt) {
    // Asynchronous operation (e.g. update info in database)
});

Application.trigger("login").then(function() {
    // Execute stuff after all (async) event handlers are done
});
```

I've looked around and haven't found any established design patterns for this.  I've got an implementation I'm happy with, but I'm curious if anyone has solved this differently?

Comment: Have you seen this: [Trigger custom event Synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338484/jquery-trigger-custom-event-synchronously)?

Comment: @DavidTansey: None of the solution presented there seem to work well

Comment: @Bergi is correct. jQuery's trigger is a synchronous operation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to add a `promises[]` property to the `evt` argument.  Asynchronous event callbacks simply add a promise to this array and the `triggerAsync` function returns a promise that wait on all the promises to settle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nonplus/9aCC4/

**Implementation of the triggerAsync** method (using Backbone events and jQuery promises, but should work for other stacks, too):

```
// Trigger an event and return promise that waits on
// event handler promises
function triggerAsync(emitter, name, evt) {
    evt || (evt={});
    evt.promises = [];
    emitter.trigger(name, evt);
    return $.when.apply(null, evt.promises);
}
```

**Usage of triggerAsync:**

```
triggerAsync(obj, "myEvent").then(function() {
    // Code executed after event handlers are done
});
```

**Implementation of an async event handler:**

```
// Async handler doing an ajax request
obj.on("myEvent", function (evt) {
    evt.promises.push($.ajax(...));
});

// Async handler doing generic async operation
obj.on("myEvent", function (evt) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    evt.promises.push(dfd.promise());

    // Async operation
    // Eventually calls dfd.resolve() or dfd.reject()
});
```

Comment: Just curious, why use `evt = _.extend({promises: []}, evt);` instead of `evt.promises = [];`?

Comment: This avoid modifying the passed-in evt object and also works if the evt parameter is undefined.

Comment: But yes, I could have initialized evt if undefined and then simply assigned the promises property.

Comment: It might be useful to more folks if your answer didn't depend on underscore just for that.  Also, in your async event handler example, it might be good to show an ajax call where you can just use the promise that is already returned rather than creating your own deferred since that is probably the most common async operation and you're already requiring jQuery.

Comment: I've simplified the example as suggested by @jfriend00

Comment: I did a double take when I saw `evt || (evt={});` as I hadn't seen that pattern before.  I'm used to seeing it like `evt = evt || {};`.